# BASS/LAME Enc: How to properly continue MP3 recording / encoding?

Tags: delphi, mp3, audio-recording, lame, bass

I've got an app which records audio from microphone and uses `BASSenc` to encode the recording as MP3 utilizing `LAME`.
If you exit the app and restart it later, you can load and continue the (recording) session.

Everything is working fine so far. However, I'm wondering what is the proper way to continue the recording / encoding stream?

At the moment I open the old file using `BASS_StreamCreateFile`, start the recording and encoder and read through the whole file using `BASS_ChannelGetData` and `BASS_Encode_Write` to "transfer" the previous data over.

I'm concerned tho that this might not be the "right" way? This step will take longer and longer the bigger the recording gets. And I also think it is lossy, because I load a lossy MP3 and reencode it, losing even more information. Isn't it? Or am I wrong?

Is there a way to tell BASSenc / LAME to just use the existing file and append stuff to it directly? Or do I already use the proper approach?

(Delphi XE7, Windows, VCL)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly append new, uncompressed data to a compressed stream without decompressing it first. So your approach seems plausible.

Size might indeed become an issue depending on the maximum intended length of your recordings. I'm handling uncompressed and compressed streams up to 1 GB, so far without experiencing major issues with delays. At least not on modern desktop machines.

However, a way to optimize the process would be to **not** load the old session data before recording the new data but instead to read it before saving the new session to disk. That way you can start recording immediately without allocating more and more RAM to the process each time.

"Right" and "wrong" becomes evident with the results. The best method is always the one that works best with the least effort to achieve it.

Multiple re-encoding, to my best knowledge, should not have any effect on quality if you didn't use a lossy codec.

Let me know if you need supporting source code for that.